# html2 canvas unable to click button

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, canvas

I am unable to click the approve button to save the signature into database. .Please help! I have refer to this link to do but they are not working.
https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Convert-Export-HTML-DIV-or-Table-to-Image-using-HTML-Canvas-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

**Code under approve button**

```html
<asp:Button ID="ProcesssOwner1" Visible="true" data-action="save" Text="Approve" CssClass="btn btn-success btn-sm" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClientClick="return ConvertToImage(this)" runat="server" OnClick="ProcesssOwner1_Click" />
```

**Javascript**

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        function ConvertToImage(ProcesssOwner1) {

            if (signaturePad.isEmpty()) {
                alert("Please provide signature first.");
                return false;
            } else {
                //document.getElementById("hfSign").value = signaturePad.toDataURL();
                html2canvas($("#drawing")[0]).then(function (canvas) {
                    var base64 = canvas.toDataURL();
                    $("[id*=hfImageData]").val(base64);
                    __doPostBack(ProcesssOwner1.name, "");
                });
                return false;
            }

        }
    </script>
```

**Code under button click**

Here I tried to save the signature in the path and folder.

```html
 protected void ProcesssOwner1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["loggedUserID"] == null && Session["loggedRoleID"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
        }
        else
        {

            int loggedUserID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["loggedUserID"]);
            List<BOL.UserInfo> userslist = new UserInfos().List();
            BOL.UserInfo loggeduser = userslist.Where(x => x.UserID == loggedUserID).FirstOrDefault();
            string app_type = "";
            string dcr = Request.QueryString["r_id"].Replace("/", "_") + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HHmmtt");
            string myID = loggeduser.EmployeeNo;
            string path1 = "/Web/";
            //System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
            if (Request.QueryString["STAT"] == "S_7")
            {
                app_type = "A";
                string base64 = Request.Form[hfImageData.UniqueID].Split(',')[1];
                byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
                //write the bytes to file:
                File.WriteAllBytes(path1 + dcr + "_" + myID + app_type + ".jpg", bytes); //write to a temp location.
                File.Copy(path1 + dcr + "_" + myID + app_type + ".jpg", @"D:\IntranetPortal\IntranetPortal\Web\signature\" + dcr + "_" + myID + app_type + ".jpg");//here we grab the file and copy it.                                                                                                                      //EDIT: based on permissions you might be able to write directly to the share instead of a temp folder first.
            }
            
            else if (Request.QueryString["STAT"] == "S_9")
            {
                app_type = "C";
                string base64 = Request.Form[hfImageData.UniqueID].Split(',')[1];
                byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
                //write the bytes to file:
                File.WriteAllBytes(path1 + dcr + "_" + myID + app_type + ".jpg", bytes); //write to a temp location.
                File.Copy(path1 + dcr + "_" + myID + app_type + ".jpg", @"D:\IntranetPortal\IntranetPortal\Web\signature\" + dcr + "_" + myID + app_type + ".jpg");//here we grab the file and copy it.
            }
            DAL.DMSS insertdata = new DMSS();
            insertdata.APP_PROCESS(Request.QueryString["r_id"], app_type, chatt.Text, path1 + "signature" + "/" + dcr + "_" + myID + app_type + ".jpg", dcr + "_" + myID + app_type + ".jpg", loggeduser.EmployeeNo, DATEE.Text);
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Approved.Thank you.');window.location ='Dms_app.aspx';", true);
        }

    }
```

Comment: unable to click the button?? do one thing, right click the button and click on inspect and see if the rendered html is valid. Also check console if some error appears there

Comment: Thanks for replying..Everything seems to be okay...no errors..

Comment: can you post the rendered HTML that you see in the browser?

Comment: how to copy that? its too long.. sorry Im new..

Comment: i am not asking you to post the whole page's html. Just post the html rendered for the button. For this open the site in chrome, right click -> inspect. Then you will be able to see the html rendered for that button

Comment: <input type="button" name="ctl00$ContentBody$ProcesssOwner1" value="Approve" onclick="return ConvertToImage(this);__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentBody$ProcesssOwner1','')" id="ContentBody_ProcesssOwner1" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-action="save">                                                                                  **This one?** @It'satrap

Comment: **Thank you for responding**...solved!!..there are no error in codes..just the url for html2canvas is no more valid..                                                    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/master/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>                                                                                                      we change the above url to =><script type="text/javascript" src="../js/html2canvas.min.js""></script> and they work

Comment: good to know that